# Simulation of a banking system with an Account class in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented, error-handling, vectors

I have been learning C++ and recently I have started practicing classes. I made this simulation of a banking system with an Account class. I would like to hear feedback on my code, what is good - what I should keep doing, and especially what I should pay more attention to, or if you have any suggestion on how to simplify parts of the code, make it more readable because I feel this could be improved. Also, I would like to hear comments on exception handling, since I am quite new to that as well. Thank you all in advance, I will do my best to implement any of your suggestions.

Account.h

```
#ifndef ACCOUNT.H
#define ACCOUNT.H
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Account{
    std::string name;
    int id;
    double balance;

public:
    Account();
    std::string getName() const;
    int getId() const;
    double getBalance() const;
    void setName(std::string);
    void setID(int);
    void setBalance(double);
    void addAccount (Account);
    void withdraw(double);
    void deposit(double);

    static std::vector<Account> accountDatabase;
};
#endif // ACCOUNT
```

Account.cpp

```
#include "Account.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

Account::Account(){
    name = "";
    id = 0;
    balance = 0;
}

std::vector<Account> Account::accountDatabase;

void Account::addAccount(Account account){
    accountDatabase.push_back(account);
}

std::string Account::getName() const{
    return name;
}

int Account::getId() const{
    return id;
}

double Account::getBalance() const{
    return balance;
}

void Account::setName(std::string userName){
    name = userName;
}

void Account::setID(int newId){
    if (newId < 1)
        throw "\n\t\t\t\t  ~ ID cannot be zero or negative ~";

    for (int i = 0; i < accountDatabase.size(); i++)
        if (newId == accountDatabase[i].getId())
            throw "\n\t\t\t\t~ Entered ID is already in use ~";

    id = newId;
}

void Account::setBalance(double newBalance){
    if (newBalance < 0)
        throw "\n\t\t\t\t  ~ Balance cannot be negative ~";

    balance = newBalance;
}

void Account::withdraw(double amount){
    if (amount < 0)
        throw "\n\t\t\t\t  ~ Withdrawal amount cannot be negative ~";

    balance -= amount;
}

void Account::deposit(double amount){
    if (amount < 0)
        throw "\n\t\t\t\t  ~ Amount for deposit cannot be negative ~";

    balance += amount;
}
```

Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Account.h"
#include <string>

void printMenu(){
    std::cout << "\n" << R"(
                                   Please select one of the following options:

                                     1. Create an account
                                     2. Check balance
                                     3. Withdraw
                                     4. Deposit
                                     5. Account summary
                                     6. Make a transaction
                                     7. Exit
                    )" << "\n\t\t\t\t--> ";
}

// get a valid input
template<typename Type>
void getInput(Type &value){
    while (true){
        std::cin >> value;
        if (std::cin.fail()){
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(100, '\n');
            std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t\t~ Invalid input ~"
            << "\n\t\t\t\t--> Enter again: ";
        }
        else {
            std::cin.ignore();
            return;
        }
    }
}

// find account in account database and return index of that account
int findAccount (int id){
    for (int i = 0; i < Account::accountDatabase.size(); i++)
        if (id == Account::accountDatabase[i].getId()) return i;

    return -1;
}

void createAccount (){
    Account newAccount;
    std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t--> Please enter your name: ";
    std::string name;
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    newAccount.setName(name);
    std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t--> Please enter your ID: ";
    int id;
    getInput(id);
    newAccount.setID(id);
    std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t--> Please enter your balance: ";
    double balance;
    getInput(balance);
    newAccount.setBalance(balance);
    // add account to the database
    newAccount.addAccount(newAccount);
    std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t~ Your account has been successfully created ~\n";
}

void MenuSelection(){

    int option = 1, account, id;
    while (option != 7){

      try{
        switch (option){
            case 1: createAccount();break;

            // check balance
            case 2:{
                    std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t--> Please enter your ID: ";
                    getInput(id);
                    account = findAccount(id);
                    if (account == -1) std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t~ ID does not match any in the database ~\n";
                    else std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t--> Your balance: " << Account::accountDatabase[account].getBalance();
                    } break;

            // withdraw money
            case 3:{
                    std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t--> Enter amount to withdraw: ";
                    double withdrawalAmount;
                    getInput(withdrawalAmount);
                    std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t--> Please enter your ID: ";
                    getInput(id);
                    account = findAccount(id);
                         if (account == -1) std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t~ ID does not match any in the database ~\n";
                         else {
                            if (Account::accountDatabase[account].getBalance() >= withdrawalAmount){
                                Account::accountDatabase[account].withdraw(withdrawalAmount);
                                std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t~ Amount successfully withdrawn ~\n";
                            }
                            else std::cout << "\n\t\t\t~ Withdrawal not successful - check the state of balance ~\n";
                         }
                    } break;

            // deposit money
            case 4:{
                    std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t--> Enter amount to deposit: ";
                    double depositAmount;
                    getInput(depositAmount);
                    std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t--> Please enter your ID: ";
                    getInput(id);
                    account = findAccount(id);
                    if (account == -1) std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t~ ID does not match any in the database ~\n";
                    else {
                            Account::accountDatabase[account].deposit(depositAmount);
                            std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t-->~ Amount successfully deposited ~\n";
                    }
                    } break;

            // print account summary
            case 5:{
                    std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t--> Please enter your ID: ";
                    getInput(id);
                    account = findAccount(id);
                    if (account == -1) std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t~ ID does not match any in the database ~\n";
                    else std::cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\t~ ACCOUNT SUMMARY ~\n"
                                   << "\n\t\t\t\t--> Name: " << Account::accountDatabase[account].getName()
                                   << "\n\t\t\t\t--> ID: " << Account::accountDatabase[account].getId()
                                   << "\n\t\t\t\t--> Balance: " << Account::accountDatabase[account].getBalance() << "\n";

                    } break;

            // make a transaction
            case 6:{
                    std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t--> Do you wish to withdraw or deposit? (w/d): ";
                    char choice;
                    std::cin >> choice;
                    std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t--> Enter transaction amount: ";
                    double amount;
                    getInput(amount);
                    std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t--> Please enter your ID: ";
                    getInput(id);
                    account = findAccount(id);
                    if (account == -1) std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t~ ID does not match any in the database ~\n";
                    else {
                         std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t--> Please enter ID of the transaction account: ";
                         getInput(id);
                         int secondAccount = findAccount(id);
                         if (secondAccount == -1) std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t~ ID does not match any in the database ~\n";
                         else {
                              bool transactionPerformed = false;
                              if (tolower(choice) == 'w' && Account::accountDatabase[secondAccount].getBalance() >= amount){
                                  Account::accountDatabase[secondAccount].withdraw(amount);
                                  Account::accountDatabase[account].deposit(amount);
                                  transactionPerformed = true;
                              }
                              else if (tolower(choice) == 'd' && Account::accountDatabase[account].getBalance() >= amount){
                                  Account::accountDatabase[secondAccount].deposit(amount);
                                  Account::accountDatabase[account].withdraw(amount);
                                  transactionPerformed = true;
                              }
                              if (!transactionPerformed) std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t~ Transaction not successful ~\n";
                              else std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t~ Transaction successfully completed ~\n";
                            }
                     }
                    }
            }
         }
         catch (const char* msg){
                std::cerr << msg;
         }
         printMenu();
         getInput(option);
         while (option < 1 || option > 7){
            std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t--> Please enter a valid option (1-7): ";
            getInput(option);
         }
    }

    std::cout << R"(
########################################################################################################################
                                  ~ THANK   YOU   FOR   USING   OUR   SERVICES ~

########################################################################################################################
                    )";
}

int main(){
    std::cout << R"(
########################################################################################################################
                                   ~ W E L C O M E   T O   O U R   B A N K ~

########################################################################################################################


                    )";
    MenuSelection();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I have a few suggestions:

- `\n\t\t\t\t` is everywhere, move it into a function which takes and returns a string, and prepends whatever string it is given with this format - the benefit of this is that if you change your formatting in the future, you only need to do it in one place.
- Getting the user to enter their ID is a common operation, so put this logic all in one place. i.e.

  ```
  std::cout << "\n\t\t\t\t--> Please enter your ID: ";
  getInput(id);
  account = findAccount(id);
  ```

  Should be lopped out into its own function, again for the same reason - if the way you want to do it changes, you only need to do it in one place!
- Move the code within each case block into its own function, e.g for `case 2`, just make a function called `checkBalance` which does exactly that. Call it from the case block (similar to how you have done for `case 1`). The comments already hint at what each block does, but the whole of the switch/case statement is quite a lot of code!
- The way you look up accounts is a little confusing and potentially inefficient for large numbers of accounts, I would use a map (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) with the key being the ID.

I hope this is enough to get you on your way, if you give this another stab then I'm happy to take another look!

Answer (score 5):

- The class is doing too much: it is not the task of the `Account` class to *also* keep a database of all accounts. Remember: *one class (or function), one responsibility*. By the same principle, `menuSelection` does too much in your main program.
- Use the initializer list in your constructor, i.e., do `Account::Account() : name_(), id_(0), balance(0) {}`. But even better, you should always [try to avoid defining default operations](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-zero), as per C.20 of the C++ Core Guidelines.
- Pass complex (i.e., not built-in types) by const-ref. This includes strings and Account types. For example, rather do `void Account::setName(const std::string& userName) { ... }`. Another possibility - if your compiler is recent enough - is to use [std::string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view).
- Avoid throwing character strings and throw proper objects instead, see [E.14](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#e14-use-purpose-designed-user-defined-types-as-exceptions-not-built-in-types).
- You seem to have an invariant which says that the balance can never be negative. I would enforce this more consistently by writing a private function like `void checkInvariant() { ... }` that makes things like `assert(balance > 0)` (but be careful when comparing floating point values to constant values; it should be done with a threshold). Then, you can add this check to suitable functions and the invariant is nicely enforced by the class itself.
- The above can help you catch errors like in `withdraw`: is it acceptable that the amount becomes negative here?